# Have an AngularJS Ui-grid Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angular-ui-grid

I have a single page application with angular js, mongoose, express and so on. Tried to use angular ui grid and have an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>       at new  (ui-grid.js:2967)
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4203)
>       at $get.w.instance (angular.js:8493)
>       at angular.js:7739
>       at r (angular.js:331)
>       at B (angular.js:7738)
>       at $get.c (angular.js:8016)
>       at g (angular.js:7117)
>       at B (angular.js:7763)
>       at g (angular.js:7117)"

this is part of my controller:

```
angular.module('flatCtrl', ['flatService', 'ui.grid'])
    .controller('FlatController', function(Flat, socketio){

        vm = this;

        Flat.allFlat()
            .success(function(data){
                vm.flats = data;
                console.log(vm.flats);
                vm.gridOptions.data = data;

            })
```

and part of HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="FlatController as flat">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

if i try to use `vm.gridOptions.data = data` after success nothing changes.

in `console.log(vm.flats)` have all my objects:

> [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,
>   Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4:
>   Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11:
>   Object

so, in data i have data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
vm.gridOptions.data = data;
```

To

```
vm.gridOptions = {};
vm.gridOptions.data = data;
```

Or

```
vm.gridOptions = { data: data }
```

And

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="FlatController as flat">
    <div ui-grid="flat.gridOptions"></div>
```

You were trying to read a `data` property of `vm.gridOptions` which is undefined so first you need define `vm.gridOptions` and set that object's `data` property.

Comment: you are forgetting one more thing.. updated the answer.. you are not using variable name correctly.. If you want to directly use your variable names in view then use `$scope` else you need to specify the controller object in your case `flat`

Comment: i'm tryin with  vm.gridOptions = {};vm.gridOptions.data = data; and with this vm.gridOptions = { data: data }.   still have an error